# How to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, kernel, 20.10, 21.10

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 on a machine which apparently would suffer [audio issues with the 21.04 kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924685). Now that 21.10 has been released, I'd like to upgrade directly from 20.10 to 21.10, but update-manager is offering to upgrade only to 21.04. I've tried following [general instructions about updating to 20.10](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-21-10) as well as the [generic upgrade instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start), both to no avail.

Is it possible to upgrade directly from 20.10 to 21.10 or must I upgrade via 21.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) or [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815).  It's not recommended. Since 20.10 is past EOL, it's generally better to cleanly install a supported release. In the future don't let your OS go EOL. LTS releases are supported for 5 years, vs 9 months for standard releases.

Comment: Download the image and take a backup of important data. Then check if the audio works properly with a live USB. Then perform a fresh install.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 was only QA-tested to upgrade to 21.04; so you wish to go outside of *supported* or *QA-tested* upgrade procedures - it's up to you.    FYI:  In QA-testing I did do an *upgrade via re-install* or *install using existing partition* where I did a *impish* upgrade over a 20.10 desktop (Lubuntu/LXQt; 20.10 had just reached EOL & I thus didn't need it anymore) install without issue; so the *upgrade via re-install* option is always a choice.

Comment: FYI:  the *upgrade via re-install* or *install using existing partition* is an install type that means packages I had installed get re-installed automatically (if available for the new release from Ubuntu repositories) & no user file/config is touched.  It allows me to use my selected (not installed by default on a Lubuntu/Xubuntu/Ubuntu..) mp3 player & have my music ready on the system without needing to backup/restore etc.   Regardless you should still backup as it's easy to make a mistake with any  installation  (it allows you to re-install same release; later, backwards etc)

Comment: @guiverc is *upgrade via re-install or install using existing partition* a new type of installation procedure? I hadn't seen it and can't find any recent information on it. It sounds like the ideal procedure for people like me who keep upgrading their system twice a year, yet would like to start afresh but don't want to reinstall their packages.

Comment: no @Jos; used to be an option you could see on (upgrade installation) `ubiquity` for some releases; but is just re-using your existing partitions (ie. *something else*, *Manual Partitioning* (`calamares`) or *Manual* (KDE-Qt skin on `ubiquity`) without any format selected - which triggers this install type.  Lubuntu has used it as a *testcase* since using `calamares` (I recently documented it here - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743 for Lubuntu; but it's not new as I've been using it since 11.04) .. it's easier on the new `canary` builds :)

Comment: @namath You wrote "In the future don't let your OS go EOL." Generally, I agree, but please note I was avoiding a known issue and I didn't really want to install 21.04 and then upgrade the kernel.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks. I'm going to try _upgrade via re-install_ and will report back.

Comment: I tried _upgrade via re-install_, but couldn't figure out the partitioning step without risking formatting my home directory, so I upgraded via 21.04 instead (which was pretty smooth).

Comment: Well done for getting the *release-upgrade* completed!    Yeah, *upgrade via re-install* was an easy option on older `ubiquity` before getting hidden away (inside *something-else*), and thus isn't a widely used feature, but the plan is for the replacement installer to make it easier to use (ie. my mention of *canary* builds in prior comment - alas it's not working there yet; but it's planned to be there before 22.04)